# Getting CSS divs to appear left

Tags: css

I'm really new to CSS and I'm having some issues with divs. I'm not quite sure how to word my question correctly and am unfamiliar with a lot of the terminology used, so I'm having trouble finding the answer to my question.

Basically, my goal is to have a container that holds several square or rectangular divs at different sizes (160x160px, 320x320px and 160x320px) so that they can be displayed in a responsive grid.

The issue I'm having is that sometimes the larger divs will 'push' things away from them; for example, the smaller divs will not appear to the left of the bottom half of the 320x320 div class.

The CSS I've written looks like this;

```
body{
    max-width: 1280px;
    background-color: #333333;
}

div{
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    height: 158px;
    width: 158px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #cc00ff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.extra{
    height: 158px;
    width: 318px;
    background-color: #ccff00;
}

.feature{
    height: 318px;
    width: 318px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

I have this linked in the HTML pasted below with about 20 divs, some with the classes for the div.

```
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="new1.css"/>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div class="feature">Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div>Article Title</div>
        <div class="extra">Article Title</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[A screenshot to illustrate what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCOwo.jpg)

I apologize again if I've worded this strangely, and would greatly appreciate any advice you could give or links to the appropriate thread that could answer my question.

Comment: The established term is *Masonry layout*: http://masonry.desandro.com/ and http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ are the most popular AFAIK

Comment: Also add your HTML , that would be helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. Masonry is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking to achieve. Is it possible to do this without Javascript?

Comment: @Uesls Not really, unfortunately. Once CSS Grid Layouts gain support in browsers, it will be possible without JavaScript.

Comment: @TylerH, thanks. Guess I'll stick with uniform divs until I'm more conversant in Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you have got some hint to design how to make it. It is not fully your solutions but here you have get key point.

```
  <head>
    <title></title>
<style>
.row1
{
height:50px;
width:100px;
background-color:green;
float:left;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
}

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <div class="row1">Article Title</div>
        <div class="row1">Article Title</div>
        <div class="row1">Article Title</div>
        <div class="row1">Article Title</div>
        <div class="row1">Article Title</div>
        <div class="row1">Article Title</div> 
        <div class="row1">Article Title</div>
        <div class="row1">Article Title</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:- 
[image]